# Exclude values equal to zero in regression line and R^2 on ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Imagine I had this data frame:

```
exampleDF <- data.frame(
   'Site' = c('s1', 's1', 's2', 's2', 's3', 's4', 's5', 's5', 's6', 's7'), 
   'xCol' = c(0, 48.75, 43.78, 48.37, 46.58, 41.22, 34.48, 39.84, 46.37, 0), 
   'yCol' = c(43.52, 0, 42.16, 40.85, 43.48, 0, 35.12, 39.14, 47.65, 41.18)
    )
```

[Resulting table (or data frame)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPArI.png)

And I have the following code for making a plot with the r-squared and the regression line on top of the dots:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)

plot <- ggplot(exampleDF, aes(x = xCol, y = yCol)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x) + 
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, aes(label = paste(..rr.label..)), parse = TRUE) + 
  ggtitle("Dem Plots") +
  xlab("X-Axis label") + ylab("Y-Axis label") +
  geom_point()

plot
```

[Resulting Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jPKno.png)

But if you can see the image, I include in the plot values that are equal to zero, which is what I want in the plot. However, I only want the regression line and the r-squared calculations to exclude when their values are equal to zero (or say, include only when values are greater than zero)

I tried manipulating the `formula` on both of these lines but I get many errors. Is there a particular syntaxis I should care when touching `y ~ x` ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach, I think, would be to split the data and plot as separate layers.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpmisc)
library(dplyr)

exampleDF <- exampleDF %>%
  group_split(zeroes = xCol == 0 | yCol == 0)

ggplot(exampleDF[[1]], aes(x = xCol, y = yCol)) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, se=FALSE, color="black", formula = y ~ x, fullrange = TRUE) + 
  stat_poly_eq(formula = y ~ x, aes(label = ..rr.label..), parse = TRUE) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_point(data = exampleDF[[2]], aes(x = xCol, y = yCol), color = "red") +
  ggtitle("Dem Plots") +
  xlab("X-Axis label") + 
  ylab("Y-Axis label")
```

[image]